# Laravel 5 Eloquent where and orwhere

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

i try to get results from table with multiple where and/or clauses. But I am not receiving the good result!

```
$queries = journal::where(function($query)
{
$term =Input::get('text');
$query->where('titre', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')
    ->where('etat','!=','9')
    ->where('type', 0)
    ->orWhere('type', 1);
})->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: can you clarify what is failing? I do notice that you use the $text variable instead of $term.

Comment: You didnt use the '$term' variable in your query. Is it intentional?

Comment: I do not receive the good result!

Comment: Sorry typo error!

Comment: and you still not getting good result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `whereBetween()` instead.

```
$queries = journal::where(function($query)
{
    $term =Input::get('text');
    $query->where('titre', 'like', '%'.$text.'%')
        ->where('etat','!=','9')
        ->whereBetween('type', [0, 1]);
})->take(10)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries - Additional Where Clauses

Answer (score 14):

You should make your query like this:

```
$query->where('titre', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')
    ->where('etat','!=','9')
    ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 0)
                  ->orWhere('type', 1);
        })
```

if you necessary wanna use orWhere otherwise use whereBetween.
[Reference Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question that was asked. Answering the question asked is helpful to folks googling a specific thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use same query there compare with dynamic value using following way:

```
$valSearch='abcd';
$query->where('field1', 'like', '%'.$val1.'%')
    ->where('field2','!=','2')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($valSearch) {
            $query->where('field3', $valSearch)
                  ->orWhere('field4', $valSearch);
        })
```

The query will execute as :

```
field1 like '%{$val1}% AND field2 != 2 AND (field3='abcd' OR field4='abcd')
```

It may helpfull to some one for later use.
[Reference Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)